# Update LAS file

Tags: laspy

I have a LAS file. I read it, read each X, Y and Z dimension, then use a script to convert the values to a customised projection. I want to update the values to the existing file.
I have tried writing a new file, however I want to make sure I do not lose any information, point attributes from the initial file.
Is it possible to update the initial file using Laspy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the file in place just open the file in read/write mode, then you can assign new values to each dimension:

```
with laspy.file.File("example.las", mode="rw") as las:
    las.x = las.x + 10
    las.y = las.y - 10
    las.z = las.z * 2
```

Comment: do you know how I can update the projection of the file? I try header.proj_id_1 = 3844, but it does not save it.

Comment: I'm not sure, might be worth posting your code in a new question

Comment: have done that here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389975/change-projection-for-las-file?noredirect=1#comment638687_389975